# MVC passing data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to pass a hidden text field to a controller, that is not part of model?

I am submitting a form and passing the model to the controller, however, the model does not contain all the fields I need.  I setup a hidden field to pass with the form, but I do not know how to get it in the controller.

In View:

```
 @model Mvc5.Models.ORDMetadata  
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Items", "Order"))
  {

   // Hidden Fields
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Order_Number, new { @Value = @TempData["OrderNumber"]} )
   @Html.Hidden("princid", (object)@TempData["PrincId"])
 }
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Items(ORDetadata model, FormCollection frm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        try
        {

            // set variables and pass to items tab
            TempData["OrderNumber"] = model.Order_Number;
            TempData["PrincId"] = frm.princid;        <=======  DOES NOT WORK       
        }
    }
```

Comment: all those are under Request.Params if they have name attribute in html , make sure in view source you should have name attribute in place

Comment: Just add additional parameters in your action method `public ActionResult Items(ORDetadata model, string princid) {...` but it would be better to create a view model with the proeprties you want to edit/display. But what is the point of rendering hidden fields and passing them back (they can't be edited)

Comment: `FormCollection` isn't a dynamic type, so you'll need to access the fields as indexes, e.g. `TempData["PrincId"] = Convert.ToString(frm["princid"])`. But Stephen's point about a dedicated `ViewModel` is the better way.

Comment: Request.Params does the job